# How to get Simple Table data in multiple SQL query php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get data from one table, I received data from one table but there is some problem in my first table i have 6 query and i allow max 12 query in result. In my query i received repeat query in my SQL please have a look. sorry for bad English.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM yt_sub,done WHERE yt_sub.current < yt_sub.total AND done.link != yt_sub.url AND done.uid != '$id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12");
```

Using this SQL query i received 12 rows but according to this sql only 6 rows pass throw it, but i received 6 rows.

Comment: *I received 12 rows ... but I received 6 rows.* Which one is the right one? It would be better if you included sample data and desired output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTINCT see below eg

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM yt_sub,done WHERE yt_sub.current < yt_sub.total AND done.link != yt_sub.url AND done.uid != '$id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12");
```

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP BY

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM yt_sub,done WHERE yt_sub.current < yt_sub.total AND done.link != yt_sub.url AND done.uid != '$id' GROUP BY done.uid ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12");
```

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong done.link != yt_sub.url AND done.uid != '$id' command is not working now.. if url and uid available in same row skip it. is i am doing something wrong or your sql has problem ?